# curve on surface of a cylinder

Tags: optimization, algebraic-curves

How can we constrain a 3D curve to be on the surface of cylinder?
I have a array of 3D points $[x_c,  y_c,  z_c]$ which take a helix kind of curve (not exactly helix) and a cylinder with given diameter $d$ (for simplicity assume that it has $z$ axis as its axis and origin as center).
I want to apply some forces on the curve in order to conform to cylinder's surface.
I used the equality constrain that the distance between the points $[x_c, y_c]$ and $[0,0]$ is equal to $d/2$.
The issue is, with this constraints, the optimization sometimes gets the curve to cross the cylinder internally. Is there any other condition which needs to be taken care of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the same condition as yours but differently written. For any point on the curve $\left(X, Y, Z\right)$ the triple must satisfy $X^2 +Y^2 = \frac{d^2}{4}$ and $Z \in [0, H]$ to keep it on the cylinder. Assuming the diameter is $d$ and the height of the cylinder is $H$. Of course the coordinate axes here are assumed to be on one of the ends of the cylinder and the $z$ axes is aligned with the axis of the cylinder.

It sounds like you are doing this on a computer, you may be having this issue due to round off errors is you are not doing things to adequate precision.